# Dunnett's test for a large number of treatments

Tags: r, anova, multiple-comparisons

I am trying to run a Dunnett's test on some toxicity data (comparing responses to a negative control), but need to compare more than 20 treatments to the control. I've written an R function to run the Dunnett's test by interpolating q' from the tables presented in Zar (1999), however the number of groups is limited to 10 in the tables. I've also tried running the procedure in Sigmaplot, however the limitation is 20 groups.

Is there a resource available to calculate or obtain q' for larger group sizes?

Note: I've tried to use the multicomp package in R, but am getting an error message while going through an example from the vignette and have emailed the author.

Edit: I've managed to get the multcomp package working, and have been able to run these tests at larger group levels (i.e., 25).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a reference to find the algorithm:
Kwong K.S. and Liu W., [Calculation of critical values for Dunnett and Tamhane's step-up multiple test procedure](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167715200000766),  Statistics and Probability Letters, Volume 49, Number 4, 1 October 2000 , pp. 411-416(6).

The algorithm is also discussed on pages 243-244 of J. Hsu, *Multiple Comparisons*. He references a web page where the Fortran code is supposed to reside, but that link no longer works.

We have improved the Dunnett test in [GraphPad Prism](http://www.graphpad.com/prism)  6 to allow up to 256 groups. Prism 6 is not out yet, but if you purchased Prism 5 (where Dunnett's test is limited to 20 groups), you'd be welcome to try a polished beta of version 6 and then get a free upgrade.

Comment: Thank you for this -- I'll work my way through the algorithm.

Comment: The Fortran code by Hsu is now here https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/hsu.1/mc.html and can be translated to C++ with http://cci.lbl.gov/fable/ (I have done it).

Answer (score 1):

I got the `multcomp` package in R working. The package will run Dunnett's tests and during initial tests handled group sizes > 20 (i.e., 25).